# select table in database using a parameter in WCF service

Tags: c#, sql, database, wcf, azure

I am still a beginner at writing C# and SQL and was wondering if someone could help me with this basic question. I have looked all over the internet and am still stuck.

I am trying to write a WCF service to access my database. I only need one method:

```
public PathDto GetPath(string src, string trg)
    {
        using (var context = new PathsEntities())
        {
            var p = (
                    from a
                    in context.src
                    where a.Target = trg
                    select a).Distance, Path;
        }
    }
```

where the parameter `src` is the table name, and the string `trg` is the entity's primary key.

Visual studio gives me the error: ...`pathsService does not contain a definition for src` because it is trying to look up the table "src" and not the string contained in the variable.

How can I use my parameter in the lookup statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using DbContext EF5.0 stuff

```
public PathDto GetPath(string tableType, string id)
{
    using (var context = new PathsEntities())
    {
            var type = Type.GetType(tableType);
            var p = context.Set(type).Find(id);
            return (PathDto)p;
    }
}
```

Seems you DON'T use EF 5.0 and have only got EF 4.0 and are using ObjectContext. Try this...no idea if it works since I don't really use EF 4.0. Alternatively download EF 5.0

```
public PathDto GetPath(string tableType, string id)
{
    using (var context = new PathsEntities())
    {
            var type = Type.GetType(tableType);
            var p = context.GetObjectByKey(new EntityKey(tableType, "id", id));
            return (PathDto)p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am now getting a "no definition for" the context.Set() method. Is this because I am missing a framework? Or do I need to declare the method myself?

Comment: I tried to implement the EF4.0 version, but I really do not understand the EntityKey stuff well enough. I have installed EF6.0 and visual studio still gives me the no definition for context.Set() What do I need to do now? Would another way be to execute a (store)query? Thanks

Comment: You will have to use the DbContext EF rather than the ObjectContext stuff. How are you creating your EF classes? Is it via the DBML xml designer? If so you need to switch to the DbContext generator (EF>4.3) instead of the ObjectContext generator(EF 4). In short you are still using EF 4.0